# How to apply jQuery on css selector :before

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

Here is my scenario, Created a `div` with `CSS` and added a `X` on top-right with before `pseudo-class`. How can I close this div by clicking on X with the help of `javascript` ?

[image]

**CSS**

```
.validation-summary-errors{
    position: absolute;
    width: 260px;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: #000 solid 1px;
    box-shadow: #232323 1px 1px 6px;
}

.validation-summary-errors:before {
    display: block;
    content: "X";
    position: absolute;
    right: -15px;
    top: -15px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #fff;
    width: 29px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**HTML in View (Edit)**

```
 <div class="message-error">  

                            @validationSummary

                    </div>
```

Comment: pseudo-class are not part of the DOM so you can not add event listeners.

Comment: `:before` is an pseudo element and cannot be accessed in the DOM!

Comment: @AlexChar any other solution you can suggest

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin).

Comment: Have a `span` or `div` with those style and use it's `click` event.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`:before` is an pseudo element and cannot be accessed in the DOM. Instead have a `span` or `div` with those style and use it's `click` event.

**Note:** Just make sure that you defined the CSS for `span.close` :-)

**Solution 1:** If you can edit the HTML.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.close').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.validation-summary-errors {
  position: absolute;
  width: 260px;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: #000 solid 1px;
  box-shadow: #232323 1px 1px 6px;
}
span.close {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  content: "X";
  position: absolute;
  right: -15px;
  top: -15px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  width: 29px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="validation-summary-errors">
  This specified email already exists
  <span class="close">X</span>
</div>
```

**Solution 2:** If HTML is created dynamically.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.validation-summary-errors').append('<span class="close">X</span>');

  $('.validation-summary-errors').on('click', 'span.close', function() {
    $(this).parent().hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.validation-summary-errors {
  position: absolute;
  width: 260px;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: #000 solid 1px;
  box-shadow: #232323 1px 1px 6px;
}
span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  content: "X";
  position: absolute;
  right: -15px;
  top: -15px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  width: 29px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="validation-summary-errors">
  This specified email already exists
</div>
```

Comment: A working example is what was missing from other comments/answers. +1

Comment: my div `validation-summary-errors` is creating dynamically, how to insert `span`

Comment: @QadeerMangrio : Check the updated answer!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `pointer-events` css attribute to ignore clicks on the parent, and not on the pseudo element. That way you can have a click listener on the parent which will only be triggered by the pseudo element.

This will be a problem if you need to allow pointer events for another reason on the parent of course.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ax9s248b/)

Comment: Ya could be good enough, the downside is that you can no more bind any mouse event to this element and btw can bring some other issue because e.g click would pass throught it. So user could click something he doesn't see/expect. But for this issue, wrapping element inside a container capturing mouse events could fix it, still guessing.

Answer (score 1):

pseudo elements are not in the DOM. You can read it thanks to the getComputedStyle method, but not manipulate it.

Instead of that create a div absolutely positionned, containing the X OR with the before class linked to. Set your listener to that div.